# CSS3: Targeting List Items

Tags: css

How do a target specific list items using CSS3. I know I can use first and last child, but I need to change the color of the second list item. I've seen this before, I think the syntax includes "^".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
li:nth-child(2)
{
    color:#ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `:nth-child`:

```
ul > li:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/peG3S/**